# Viewing a log of my chat activity

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

Is there a way to view our chat log?

If there is such feature, how do I go about activating it or seeing my log?

**Update:** The chat message history list that I'm looking for should look something like the "answers"/"questions" tabs found in our profile; listing the messages that each of us have posted and also the respective chat room in which they were posted.

Comment: I don't understand why I am down-voted. Please at least state the reason or leave a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: `voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness` It is still weird, I'm not suggesting a new feature but asking if there is such a feature at the moment, hoping for a yes or no. Does this mean they are disagreeing with me trying to view my own chat log?

Comment: This is like receiving a yellow card right when you have just stepped onto a soccer field.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because your question was initially somewhat unclear; this feature shouldn't be controversial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to view your individual chat transcript from the existing chat UI. I believe there's an existing question asking for this, I can't find a reference to that though

Answer (score 2):

The number of messages is shown in the lower right corner. Clicking it will take you to the chat log.

[image: pointer]

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping out. But erm, I'm actually looking for a list of only our own chat messages, like a chat history or something.

Comment: Who do you mean by "our"?

Comment: It's about time I got featured in a screenshot.

Comment: The "our" refers to each individual user. The chat message history list that I'm looking for should look something like the "answers"/"questions" tabs found in our profile; listing the messages that each of us have posted and also the respective chat room in which they were posted.